# Accessing images saved in volumeMounts outside cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, k3s, persistent-volume-claims

I have created a workflow which stores images in volumeMounts in K3S, for that I have created PersistentVolumeClaim which is storing all the incoming images.

I have a web interface where I would like to view images. So far I do not see any documentation to read images outside K3S cluster. I have done web application routing through ingress controller. What is the correct way to access data stored in the volumeMounts using ingress route? In my case I want to have serveble URL which I can use in my web application to visualise.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Images as in pictures? Or Images as in container-images?

Comment: Images as in pictures

Answer (score 0):

hello, hope you are enjoying your kubernetes Journey !

It depends of your configurations:
What is the backend volumes you are using?
Do you use a database?

If you Can add your deployment manifest (with your container images Will be even better), it'll help me reproduce your case.

However, with the lack of these informations, here is what i can propose you:

Store the images in a DB or directly in a volume mount path into your pod, and configure your app to go read these images from that path.

Do not hesitate to share more info, i'll be glad to help you.